# Fixing skirting board with adhesive

Tags: adhesive, skirting

I want to use adhesive to put a couple of skirting boards, mainly because I have no idea where the electric cables are running and I don't want to take a chance.

I have been advised to use "Alcolin Skirting Board Adhesive", http://www.alcolin.com/diy-products/wall-and-floor/skirting-board-adhesive

I have ~2.7m long boards and the wall are fairly straight and painted.

My Question is, how good are those adhesive? Will I be able to nail things in them for example, (like cables or whatever).
Will it work for a month and then start to fall apart slowly?

I know that screws are ultimately better, but are adhesives not as good an option?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I ended up using the adhesive and it worked great, even on the long boards.

But remember:

- My walls are concrete, and clean
- My walls are straight as an arrow, (no weird holes or angles).
- It took 24hrs for the adhesive to cure properly, (not 1hr as claimed by the manufacturer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used Alcolin, I usually use Henery's for "mop boards" & cove base the adhesives are really good. If you want to remove them you usually do a lot of damage to the sheet rock / or take chunks of plaster out. The adhesives will last as long as the board or wall do. Once they set I think tacking a cord on it will be fine if allowed by local code. No worries about the adhesive falling apart usually the wall or inexpensive trim breaks down first.

Comment: Thanks, not sure if allowed by local code... never thought of that been a rule. I'll need to check.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you without nice straight walls who want to do this:

Pick up a bunch of concrete blocks, and some of that rubber mesh tool drawer liner.

A chunk of drawer liner with a block of concrete on it has an impressive amount of sliding friction.  Push against the baseboard while the glue is setting.

If you goof up and end with gaps, paintable caulk to your rescue.